# how to install oracle database express on mac m1

Tags: database, oracle, apple-m1, oracle19c

I want to Install Oracle Database Express on macbook m1 but it only supports linux and windows, I downloaded Sql developer but I m unable to download Oracle database. I tried to install using docker and OrcaleVM but both attempt were unsuccessfull. I also tried playonmac but it only supports x86 software and x64 software crashes when i try to run. What should i do to install oracle database express on macbook with M1 chip??

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the Oracle Database team hasn't released a build for ARM chipsets yet.
I had a similar issue (w/ docker) and solved it by following [these steps](https://github.com/gvenzl/oci-oracle-xe/issues/63#issuecomment-1146660581):

1. Uninstall docker desktop if installed
2. Run `brew install colima`
3. Run `brew install docker`
4. Run `colima start --memory 4 --arch x86_64`
5. Run an Oracle DB image using docker (e.g `docker run -e ORACLE_RANDOM_PASSWORD=yes -p 1521:1521 -d gvenzl/oracle-xe`)

This should successfully run a container w/ an Oracle DB on the new M1 Macs.

Answer (score 2):

It seams that the only way today is to use parallel desktop with an ARM Windows.
To download it you have to register for the Windows Insider Program:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windowsinsiderpreviewARM64

It should works:
https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/issues/1814#issuecomment-826554712

Comment: You can use UTM as an open source alternative to Parallels Desktop

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't answer the question directly, but... A solution worth considering for M1 Mac users is using the Oracle-cloud database. It's "always free" so it's not a trial that expires after a certain time period. It's essentially having your own oracle database in the cloud that you can connect to natively from your own machine

https://www.oracle.com/cloud/free/

Comment: Even after giving them credit card details sign up still fails.

Comment: Not sure where your sign up process differed from mine.... I don't remember ever having to give credit-card details at all for the always-free tier

Comment: Go through https://www.oracle.com/cloud/free/ eventually you'll be asked for a credit card. They may have changed their policy recently, I'm not sure.

Comment: Your credit card is used for identification purposes. You will not be charged for the trial account nor for "Always Free Resources".

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling to find a solution to this for the past couple of days, and finally have a halfway-decent solution. I've had success running Oracle Linux 8 (x86_64) with [UTM](https://mac.getutm.app/), and then installing Oracle DB 21c EE in the VM. The setup, configuration and installation is completely manual and will take a significant chunk of time, but the outcome is pretty satisfactory. Mouse didn't work for me, so the GUI is pretty much useless. From what I've read, hardware acceleration doesn't work either, so my recommendation is to stay away from the UI as much as you can. I used keyboard to navigate the OL8 installer, and selected the "server" installation mode with headless packages. The install script ([here](https://github.com/oracle/vagrant-projects/tree/main/OracleDatabase/21.3.0)) from the vagrant project was quite helpful in installing and configuring the DB. Performance-wise, I've found it to be quite snappy (to be fair, I've just tested the basics). The VM consumes ~5GB RAM of the 8GB I've allocated to it. In terms of CPU, I've allocated four cores to the VM, but I haven't seen it use any more than 50% of one core. Again, I use it for very basic CRUD requests, so that's all I've tested it with. And just to give a little context, I'm on the M1 MBA with 16GB RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Apple M1 specifically, it is a 'known' issue.

**Below solution worked for me:** You probably installed node with either nvm or brew, by doing that you will install the arm64 version and get this error. The only solution for now is to download and install node from the homepage directly.

**Read below for reference:**
https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues/1349

Answer (score -3):

You can install oracle db on apple silicon Mac’s

Oracle Database on Apple Silicon MacBook | M1, M2
https://youtu.be/GJyCY3F0mmI

Comment: I'd like to read an explanation what to expect in the video. Not only a link to it. I stopped watching as soon as windows appeared.

Comment: Apparently there is no other way of installing oracle db on apple silicon based Mac since it doesn’t support arm architecture. Thankfully the windows in parallels does the x86-64 emulation and hence oracle db works

Comment: The answer from @salah3x explains how to run the oracle database with cpu emulation and no windows.

Comment: I don’t see any one responding that it has worked. Has it worked for you?

Comment: 3 people found it useful. Yes the colima based solution does work for me.

Comment: Ok. But from a DBA point of view we can’t do the complete administration right? Such as access to control files, backup and restore etc. colima based solution is for someone who needs ready db specially for pl/SQL developer not for DBA’s.